# Jenkins move from rolling release to stable (LTS) release

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins rolling release, I was trying to move to LTS release of jenkins but I didn't found a direct way to move from rolling release to LTS version.

There are lot's of configuration in my older Jenkins, so just can't install fresh Jenkins.

Is there any way to move from rolling release to LTS version?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LTS+Release+Line :

1. Back up your Jenkins installation (for example the entire Jenkins directory)
2. Download desired jenkins.war version, in this case LTS one
3. Shut down Jenkins
4. Copy new jenkins.war over the old one in you Jenkins directory
5. Start Jenkins again
6. Follow this quote from above wiki page:

   > If you had a Latest&Greatest release running before and now have
   >   switched to LTS, you should open Manage Jenkins->Manage
   >   Plugins->Advanced and press "Check now". This way you ensure to get
   >   the proper update notifications for LTS and LTS-compatible plugins
   >   instead of Latest&Greatest. After you do this you may need to remove
   >   the contents of ${JENKINS_HOME}/updates to ensure that Jenkins shows
   >   the correct updates for the LTS stream.

Comment: This works but the last note about removing the contents of `updates` folder does not seem to work. I still get recommendations to update to the weekly version instead of the LTS version (currently at the latest LTS version). https://stackoverflow.com/q/41452225/266535

Comment: I fixed the problem of getting notified about weekly releases by deleting the 'updates' folder.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to above answer, just remove updates folder doesn't work for me on Ubuntu.

Here is the logic for my understanding,

```
1. For first LTS version intallation, LTS updates json file in 
   installed. It feteches LTS version and update accordingly to next LTS json.
2. But if once you used rolling version, it updates the "updates" 
   jason into rolling version.
3. Even if you delete updates folder, for next bootup, even it is LTS 
   version, it generates rolling version updates folder. Then it
   checks rolling version again.
```

So to restore it back to LTS version,

```
1. Stop Jenkins
2. Delete updates folder
3. Install latest LTS version on another PC with "sudo apt-get install jenkins".
4. Copy the updates folder to current Jenkins folder
5. Restart Jenkins
```

At this time, you get LTS updates folder and it will not fetch rolling version again.