# Upgrade from Jenkins Weekly to LTS

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to upgrade from a lower version of Jenkins weekly release to the latest Jenkins LTS release? I initially installed a version of the weekly in an effort to get a plugin that was in beta to work correctly.

The LTS version since then now fixes my issue and I would like to move back to the LTS release.

Edit:

It's installed via the Windows installer. The actual Jenkins UI gives me a prompt to upgrade to the latest but its always weekly release rather than LTS. I'll try manually updating the war.

Comment: How did you install it. Because basically it is just downloading the `jenkins.war` and copying it to the location where the current `jenkins.war` is. Then restart jenkins. If you used a package manager, I assume you can just install it from there by installing a specific version.

Comment: Like you said, update it manually: 1) Stop the Jenkins Windows Service. 2) Replace the jenkins,war file. 3) Start the Service. I would also make a backup of the whole Jenkins folder before updating.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem. It always says "new version of jenkins x.x is available" even though jenkins is on the latest LTS but the weekly version is showing up.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem of getting notified about weekly releases by deleting the 'updates' folder.